# dll files though present do not get loaded

Tags: php, windows, apache, dll

I get a `php` warning:

```
[06-Jan-2016 13:50:15 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/MAS/php/ext\php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[06-Jan-2016 13:50:15 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/MAS/php/ext\php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[06-Jan-2016 13:50:15 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/MAS/php/ext\php_ldap.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

 in Unknown on line 0
```

The `dll` files are there in the right directory. Why could be the reason then, I get this error?

I am running : `PHP Version 5.6.15` and `Apache Version Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.15`. I believe that they both are compatible with each other. Both `php` and `apache` are `32bit` but windows `64bit`.

Comment: May I ask where did you get this dlls from?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos They were there inside the package.

Comment: Is your PHP directory in your `%PATH%` system variable?

Comment: Rational: apache modules have interdependencies. I know that `php_curl` requires `php_zlib` and must include it in order to function properly. If it fails finding it, the module will not be loaded and trigger that warning. The same must be happening with the other modules.

Comment: Oh, heads up: Windows requires you to reboot your computer in order to export system variables and make them available to applications.